# bash| assign arguments to variables while escaping spaces

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, escaping

This is bash script which prints framerate of a video and the argument it takes may contain spaces. also this argument is going to be used in a command inside the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
inputVid="$*"

#checking if $inputVid has full path 
echo $inputVid

frames=`ffmpeg -i $inputVid 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p"`
echo $frames
```

when I execute

```
$./frameRate.sh ../Downloads/FlareGet/Videos/Why\ .mp4
```

output is:

```
../Downloads/FlareGet/Videos/Why .mp4
```

so the filename is getting passed correctly but spaces are not getting escaped hence no output from ffmpeg

is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Enclose the filename in double quotes?

Comment: @codeforester I am also going to pass the argument as a variable from another python script so quoting the filename isn't an option for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your command only takes one argument, use `$1`. All you need to do is properly quote both the original argument *and* the parameter `$1` inside your script.

```
# Equivalent invocations
$ ./frameRate.sh ../Downloads/FlareGet/Videos/Why\ .mp4
$ ./frameRate.sh ../Downloads/FlareGet/Videos/"Why .mp4"
$ ./frameRate.sh "../Downloads/FlareGet/Videos/Why .mp4"
```

The script would be

```
inputVid="$1"
ffmpeg -i "$inputVid" 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p"
```

or simply

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p"
```

If this does't work, then your Python script is not passing the argument correctly, and there is isn't really anything you can do to accommodate it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using double quotes around your input variable you should use `ffprobe` instead of `ffmpeg` to get media file information. The output from `ffmpeg` is intended for informational purposes only and is not to be parsed by scripts: it is considered "fragile" and is not guaranteed to provide a standard, consistent format. Using `ffprobe` will also allow you to eliminate `sed`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Output file path and name
echo "$1"

# Output average frame rate
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1"
```